# MySQL Dynamic Pivot Table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, pivot

I have the following dynamic pivot working using MySQL Workbench. I however have problem of executing it using PHP. I have tried so many for the past 7 days, but it just doesn't work. Need some light of how the PHP code should be like to get this running.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET group_concat_max_len=15000;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'COUNT(IF(int_supplierid = ',
      int_supplierid,
      ', int_projectid, NULL)) AS NO',
      int_supplierid
    )
  ORDER BY int_supplierid) INTO @sql
FROM tbl_po;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT int_userid, ', @sql, ' FROM tbl_po GROUP BY int_userid');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The first php code I used;

```
<?php
require_once('myconn.php');

$approval="SET @sql = NULL;
SET group_concat_max_len=15000;"

$approval3="
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'COUNT(IF(int_supplierid = ',
      int_supplierid,
      ', int_projectid, NULL)) AS NO',
      int_supplierid
    )
  ORDER BY int_supplierid) INTO @sql
FROM tbl_po;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT int_userid, ', @sql, ' FROM tbl_po GROUP BY int_userid');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;"

$RSFeed2 = mysql_query($approval) or die(mysql_error());
$RSFeed2 = mysql_query($approval3) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_RSFeed = mysql_num_rows($RSFeed2);
echo $RSFeed2['int_userid'];
echo $totalRows_RSFeed;
?>
```

The second one that I used and tried;

```
$host="127.0.0.1";
$port=3306;
$socket="";
$user="root";
$password="pwd";
$dbname="kelupis";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
    or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

//1st query
$query1 = "SET @sql = NULL;
SET group_concat_max_len=15000; SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT     CONCAT('COUNT(IF(int_supplierid = ',int_supplierid,', int_projectid, NULL)) AS NO',int_supplierid)   ORDER BY int_supplierid) INTO @sql FROM tbl_po;";


if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query1)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($int_supplierid);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s\n", $int_supplierid);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to post some PHP code that you're using to execute this query.

Comment: Is that a stored procedure?

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Does it throw an error?

Comment: Thanks for all replies. Edited with php code included.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's mysql API doesn't support multi-query.

In other words, you can't prepare and execute a string that contains multiple SQL statements separated by semicolons.

Likewise, mysqli doesn't support multi-query with the plain mysqli::query() function.  You must use [mysqli::multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

But multi-query is [really a bad idea](http://xkcd.com/327/).  You should stick with executing statements one by one.

PS:  The mysql extension is [deprecated anyway](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) as of PHP 5.3.0, so you should use mysqli or PDO in any new code.

---

I see from your examples that you're trying to do a dynamic pivot.  You want one column for each supplierid, and the value of the column should be the count of that supplierid.

It's far simpler and more efficient to output these counts as *rows*, not columns:

```
$query = "SELECT int_supplierid, COUNT(int_projectid) 
    FROM tbl_po GROUP BY int_supplierid";

if (!($stmt = $con->prepare($query))) {
    die($con->error);
}
if (!$stmt->execute()) { 
    die($stmt->error); 
}
$stmt->bind_result($int_supplierid, $no);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf("%s: %d\n", $int_supplierid, $no);
}
```

Comment: Sorry Bill. I have tried and tried. Went away for a break. Redo it again and again. I cant seem to get it. Seriously need help here